# Spinner linked to a timer Android

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, timer, android-spinner

I want to add a 10 second int array to a spinner and link it to timer so that a picture self destructs for the amount of seconds a user selects.

```
onCreate() method:

int[] seconds ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        mSeconds = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.secondsSpinner);
```

I am not sure how to get the numbers to show in spinner.Also I want to add title to each number so 1 **second** and then 2 **seconds** etc.I can't put the seconds title in spinner as we then can not select the int number (then array will be string array not int array).

How can I get the number of users selects from the drop down on spinner?

I would like to link the array to timer to count down the number so image self destructs.I am very new to android development so I am very stuck. btw i am using fragments

Comment: This would give you an idea on how to load spinner http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/04/spinner-with-different-displat-text-and.html Try this and then let us know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a String array to do the job for you, use it to set the titles then use a selection listener to get the number you want.

```
String titles[] = {"1 Second","2 Seconds", ...};

mSeconds = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.secondsSpinner);

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, titles);
arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
           int secondsToUse = position + 1;
            // or if you still want to use an int array
            // int secondsToUse = seconds[position];
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // do nothing
        }

    });
```

Comment: `(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, titles);` this displays red line under it and so does `secondsToUse `

Comment: do i put something in place of the question mark here `AdapterView<?> ` and this`(new OnItemSelectedListener() {` was changed to this ` new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()`

Comment: you dont have to change the ? the rest is ok its the same thing.